# Retrieving value from ajax response

Tags: jquery

I use jQuery .ajax to send data and then I listen for response. The response contains data in the following format, when I use `console.log()`

```
{
    "res": 65,
    "arr": [
        {
            "id": "17",
            "item": "large book",
            "rate": "5"
        },
        {
            "id": "18",
            "item": "2 cups",
            "rate": "5"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to output this information withing JS function, so I try to lop:

```
for(var i=0; i <response.arr; i++){
  // HOW DO I GET: 
  // Item: large book
  // Item: 2 cups
}
```

`return response.arr['item']` does not seem to work.

Comment: What would `i <response.arr` even mean? `arr` is an *array*, and you don't do anything to index into it.

Comment: Please show full code context.... that `return` is highly suspicious even after `for` is fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `arr` property contains an array, you need to access it via index in your `for` loop. Also note you need to iterate over the `length` of `response.arr`. Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.arr.length; i++){
    var item = response.arr[i].item;
    console.log(item);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f569k2pg/)

As you've tagged this question with jQuery, you can also use that to loop over the returned object:

```
$.each(response.arr, function(i, obj) {
    console.log(obj.item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to parse the json string to json object using function:

```
var json = JSON.parse(response);
```

Then, to iterate only array do the following:

```
for(var i = 0; i < json["arr"].length; i++) {
      console.log(json["arr"][i].item);          
}
```